# Initialize bunch of variables in constructor by extracting value from dictionary

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `headers` dictionary value being passed to one of my constructors and based on that dictionary value I am extracting individual headers I need and setting all my variables.

```
public Tester(IDictionary<string, StringValues> headers)
 {
     int textId = 0;

     if (headers == null)
     {
         ProcId = GenerateProcId();
         DbId = GenerateDbId();
         ThetaId = GenerateThetaId();
         return;
     }

     ProcIdHeader = GetHeaderValue(headers, PROC_HEADER);
     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ProcIdHeader))
     {
         ProcId = GenerateProcId();
     }
     else
     {
         ProcId = ProcIdHeader;
     }

     DbIdHeader = GetHeaderValue(headers, DB_HEADER);
     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DbIdHeader))
     {
         DbId = GenerateDbId();
     }
     else
     {
         DbId = DbIdHeader;
     }

     ThetaId = GenerateThetaId();

     var textIdStr = GetHeaderValue(headers, TEXT_HEADER);
     int.TryParse(textIdStr, out textId);
     TextIdValue = textId;
     TextId = textId;

     AlphaHeader = GetHeaderValue(headers, ALPHA_HEADER);
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AlphaHeader))
     {
         AlphaContent = AlphaHeader;
     }

     TimeoutIdHeader = GetHeaderValue(headers, TIMEOUT_HEADER);
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TimeoutIdHeader))
     {
         TimeoutId = TimeoutIdHeader;
     }

     FilterHeader = GetHeaderValue(headers, FILTER_HEADER);
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FilterHeader))
     {
         FilterId = FilterHeader;
     }

     PreviewHeader = GetHeaderValue(headers, PREVIEW_HEADER);
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PreviewHeader))
     {
         PreviewId = PreviewHeader;
     }

     AntHeader = GetHeaderValue(headers, ANT_HEADER);
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AntHeader))
     {
         AntId = AntHeader;
     }
     LocalHeader = GetHeaderValue(headers, LOCAL_HEADER);
     AppHeader = GetHeaderValue(headers, APP_HEADER);
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AppHeader))
     {
         AppId = AppHeader;
     }

     ContextHeader = GetHeaderValue(headers, CONTEXT_HEADER);
     if (ContextHeader != null)
     {
         try
         {
             ContextStr = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ContextStr>(ContextHeader);
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             ContextStr = new ContextStr();
         }
     }
     if (LocalHeader != null)
     {
         try
         {
             LocalStr = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<LocalStr>(LocalHeader);
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             LocalStr = new LocalStr();
         }
     }
     PageHeader = GetHeaderValue(headers, PAGE_HEADER);
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PageHeader))
     {
         PageStr = PageHeader;
     }
     ChannelId = GetHeaderValue(headers, CHANNEL_HEADER);
 }

 private string GetHeaderValue(IDictionary<string, StringValues> headers, string headerKey)
 {
     headers.TryGetValue(headerKey, out var headerValues);
     if (headerValues.Count > 0) return headerValues[0];
     return null;
 }
```

I wanted to see if there is any better way to rewrite the constructor logic that I have. As of now it looks very bulky with bunch of if/else block. Anything that can be improve in my code?

**Note:** It's a legacy code base system so changing whole design might be difficult but little refactoring by splitting it into various methods is possible.

Comment: use `Factory` design pattern, and work with each header individually, make strong-typed headers. Then, group your work under one class that would initiate them all (or prepare them for use).

Comment: yeha Factory pattern might work for me but I was thinking instead of that can we simplify if/else block by making some sort of method that can do all the work and we will just pass headers or header values to it? Something like that. Since it's a legacy code base so don't want to touch multiple things by using factor pattern here.

Comment: `Since it's a legacy code base so don't want to touch multiple things by using factor pattern here` you should mention that in your post, so others will know what are you dealing with, and what is your expectation.

Comment: @iSR5 just edited my question. thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify that portion of code. First, you'll need to create an array that will holds the header keys such as `PROC_HEADER` ..etc. then you can go from there.

Here is an example (NOTE, keys are just placeholders in this example, so you know which const needs to be replaced).

```
public Tester(IDictionary<string, StringValues> headers)
 {
    // these will be overwritten if their customer global are not null. 
    DbId = GenerateDbId();
    ProcId = GenerateProcId();
    ThetaId = GenerateThetaId();

    if (headers == null) { return; }

    var headerKeys = new[]{
        "PROC_HEADER",
        "DB_HEADER",
        "TEXT_HEADER",
        "ALPHA_HEADER",
        "TIMEOUT_HEADER",
        "FILTER_HEADER",
        "PREVIEW_HEADER",
        "ANT_HEADER",
        "APP_HEADER",
        "PAGE_HEADER",
        "LOCAL_HEADER",
        "CONTEXT_HEADER",   
        "CHANNEL_HEADER"
    };

    foreach(var key in headerKeys)
    {
        headers.TryGetValue(key, out var headerValue);

        if (headerValue.Count > 0)
        {   
            switch(key)
            {
                case "PROC_HEADER":
                    SetHeaderValue(headerValue[0], "ProcIdHeader", "ProcId");
                    break;
                case "DB_HEADER":
                    SetHeaderValue(headerValue[0], "DbIdHeader",  "DbId");  
                    break;      
                case "TEXT_HEADER":
                     int.TryParse(headerValue[0],  var textId);
                     TextIdValue = textId;
                     TextId = textId;               
                    break;              
                case "ALPHA_HEADER":
                    SetHeaderValue(headerValue[0],  "AlphaHeader",  "AlphaContent");
                    break;
                case "TIMEOUT_HEADER":
                    SetHeaderValue(headerValue[0],   "TimeIdHeader",  "TimeId");        
                    break;      
                case "FILTER_HEADER":
                    SetHeaderValue(headerValue[0],   "FilterHeader",  "FilterId");      
                    break;          
                case "PREVIEW_HEADER":
                    SetHeaderValue(headerValue[0],   "PreviewHeader",  "PreviewId");        
                    break;          
                case "ANT_HEADER":
                    SetHeaderValue(headerValue[0],   "AntHeader",  "AntId");    
                    break;      
                case "APP_HEADER":
                    SetHeaderValue(headerValue[0],   "AppHeader",  "AppId");    
                    break;  
                case "PAGE_HEADER":
                    SetHeaderValue(headerValue[0],   "PageHeader",  "PageStr"); 
                    break;   
                case "CHANNEL_HEADER":
                    ChannelId = headerValue[0];     
                    break;  
                case "LOCAL_HEADER":
                    LocalHeader = headerValue[0];
                    LocalStr = DeserializeHeader<LocalStr>(LocalHeader);
                    break;      
                case "CONTEXT_HEADER":
                    ContextHeader = headerValue[0];
                    ContextStr = DeserializeHeader<ContextStr>(ContextHeader);
                    break;                                           
            }       
        }   
    }
}

private T DeserializeHeader<T>(string str) where T : new()
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
        try
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(str);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new T();
        }
    }

    return default;
}

public void SetHeaderValue(string headerValue, string customerPropertyName, string serverPropertyName)
{
    var custProperty = this.GetType().GetProperty(customerPropertyName);        

    if(custProperty != null) { custProperty.SetValue(this, headerValue); }

    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headerValue))
    {      
        var serverProperty = this.GetType().GetProperty(serverPropertyName);

        if(serverProperty != null) { serverProperty.SetValue(this, headerValue); }                       
    }      

}
```

I've decided to use `switch` to group them up, as it would be more readable, and also it has an a performance advantage over if/else blocks as it would be compiled into jump table which would be faster than if/else blocks.

Comment: thanks for your solution. can you also explain why this is better than my original solution so that I can understand better? I had bunch of if/else block but you have bunch of cases. Just trying to understand advantages of this over original.

Comment: @dragons sure, I've updated my answer, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: cool. going through your answer now. There is a spell check on this line `if (headerValues.Count > 0)`.

Comment: @dragons good catch, I've fixed it.

Comment: I think you are missing one more thing. For some headers - I have two fields for example I have `ProcId` and `ProcIdHeader` for `PROC_HEADER` and I need to use both bcoz they both will be sent to db. In your example you removed one and just using `ProcId`.

Comment: @dragons that's what made me confused, both will have mostly the same value, why declaring both as global variables in the first place I didn't know, but since you cleared that out, I will fix it. but this is a really bad design.

Comment: @dragons yes it's true and also it depends on the collection type. You might find some cases a foreach would be faster than a for loop. So, it depends on the collection type optimization, and what your code is optimized for. but in most cases, a for loop is much cheaper than foreach loop. You can do some tests on various of collections using different kind of loops to measure their performance against each collection type to see the difference yourself.

Comment: @dragons the other hand is readability, in a dictionary for instance, a foreach loop is more readable than using a for loop. you can test the difference, and decide if is it worth the change or not.